# C# Web Api 2.1 return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've created a new C# WebApi 2.1 from MVC Empty template and I don't know why, when I create a custom route, it returns 404. Otherwise it works fine.

```
Global.asax
```

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

```
WebApiConfig.cs
```

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
    }
}
```

Working route (`ChannelsController.cs`):

```
// GET api/channels
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int page = 1, [FromUri] int pageSize = 12)
{
    ...
}
```

Route returning 404 (`VideosController.cs`)

```cs
[Route("api/channels/{channelId}/videos")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetVideosByChannelId(int channelId, [FromUri] int page = 1, [FromUri] int pageSize = 12) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you check something for me please? Are you definitely calling the API with `channels` not `channeles` for the second example? I copied your code locally to try, and it all worked, except for me having to rename `ChannelesController` to `ChannelsController`. I know you said that route is the one that's working, but it makes me wonder if you have a simple typo you've copied that's giving you the 404 on the second route. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRi6e.png

Comment: @JohnH oopsie, i fixed the typo

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. It means I'm unable to reproduce though. Both routes are working for me.

Comment: @JohnH ha crap, I,ve found the problem. Was just a stupid typo in the name of the class (i don't know why though!!). There was a 1 at the end. VideosController1... Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Haha, no problem!